# Multiple lines of a label in a custom UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have searched around for any tip for my problem. But I cannot find a solution for this.

I have made a subclass of UITableviewCell (FeedCell). With one image and two labels. 
The problem is that the label I need to be multiline does not show up with multilines.

I use autolayot.

This is an app who display the users twitterfeed.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

FeedCell *tweetCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (tweetCell == nil) {
    tweetCell = [[FeedCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [tweetCell.tweetText setNumberOfLines:0];
    [tweetCell.tweetText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [tweetCell.tweetText setFont:[self fontForCell] ];


}
NSDictionary *tweet = _dataSource[[indexPath row]];

NSString *tweetString = [tweet valueForKey:@"text"];

tweetCell.name.text =[tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];


[tweetCell.tweetText setText:tweetString];

return tweetCell;
```

}

I have also set the heigthforRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *tweet = _dataSource[[indexPath row]];
NSString *theText=[tweet valueForKey:@"text"];
UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [theText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return labelSize.height + 20;
```

}

The problem is that the tweet cell.tweetText does not show up with multilines. I have not tried this with another CellStyle (I use custom cellstyle).

Any tip anyone?

Comment: could you log the frame of your label?

Comment: What layout and number of lines have you set?

Comment: i think you need to customize your own subclass of cell

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here's a quick example of how I did something similar: [github](https://github.com/rjowens/dynamicCellHeight)

Comment: Ahh. You added those labels at runtime in code. I have made those in the storyboard view. That could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

For mutiline use the following:

```
tweetCell.tweetText.numberOfLines = 0;
[tweetCell.tweetText sizeToFit];
```

for testing purpose set the height of row as 46.0f in the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

I could not get the height issue fixed but this did give me a UILabel with multiple lines

Comment: This is the same answers I have red all over the Internet. So it seems like there is som other issues that I may have cracked up. If anyone would like to take a shot, here is the complete classes: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fcu61xr532l6q4q/BEiNRih3az

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but it came up when I was searching.

I got an example like this by following http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout.

I think for iOS8 the following is required:

- Setting the lines to 0
- Setting the word wrap
- Setting the label size to be >= 20
- Making sure there are enough constraints to determine the cell height (height of title and vertical spacing)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[tweetCell.tweetText  sizeToFit]
```

Comment: No success. This is a screenshot of the feed. The line height seems right. But the label of tweet does not show with multilines. https://www.dropbox.com/s/olilnuc0edqu62i/Skjermbilde%202013-09-03%20kl.%2022.24.29.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to show 2 line of text (minimum 1 and maximum 2), the `numberOfLines` must be set to 2. Setting it to 0 means no limit.

Secondly, setting just the number of lines is not enough. The label width HAS to be specified. Either use `sizeToFit`, or set a constant value.

Comment: Also, I would advise setting the attributes of your `UITableViewCell` elements in your `init` method of the custom class. Just a personal opinion, it's not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code that sets number of lines, linebreakmode, and font OUTSIDE of those curly braces