# Swift: Auto layout and table view cells with dynamic heights

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I've created a test project to understand table cells with variable heights. I've read a number of tutorials on StackOverflow and elsewhere but I'm still doing something wrong, and I'm not quite sure what.

**How do I ensure that regardless of the string length, the table cell's height changes to accommodate all of the text?**

Here I set up my table view with an array of strings of various lengths.

Here's what my simulator shows, as well as my code:

[image: tableview]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items: [String] = ["We", "Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.", "Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum", "Blah", "one two three", "Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.", "gum gum gum gum"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130.0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool { return true }
}
```

In my storyboard, I have a single test cell set up with some constraints (which may be done incorrectly, not sure). Constraints seem to be the crux of nailing this implementation or totally screwing it up

[image: contraints]

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sorry what's your actual question? what's the problem?

Comment: My problem is that the cells should be variable heights to include all of the text in the item of the array. Instead, they're truncated with a `...`. I'll re-add this in the question too so it's clearer

Comment: did you make the label in the UITableViewCell a multi-line label?

Comment: It's currently set to 0. I've tried it with values 1-5 too, nothing changes

Comment: I have the same issue like you. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: When I was using storyboards, the problem was not using autolayout correctly to make sure that each element was placed with appropriate constraints, widths and heights. I've since stopped using storyboards and started using Cartography (https://github.com/robb/Cartography) to do manual layout for more control. This isn't really a problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

To use autolayout with multi-line labels, you need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property (in `viewDidLoad` or elsewhere appropriately). This will cause autolayout to "do the right thing" and make your label expand to a multi-line label. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth

Note that for this to work properly inside a UITableViewCell, you should also response to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` - see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I don't believe either of these are correct answers, from the research I've done. `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130.0` are intended to work with autolayout constraints to basically set a minimum or calculate a dimension automatically. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` seems to override with a hard constant

Comment: I can't help you if you don't believe the documentation is correct...clearly in Apple's documentation: This property affects the size of the label when layout constraints are applied to it. During layout, if the text extends beyond the width specified by this property, the additional text is flowed to one or more new lines, thereby increasing the height of the label.

Comment: And in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you compute the height of the label after it has been "autolayout"-ed, and return this height.

Comment: Here's an example how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600047/multiple-lines-of-a-label-in-a-custom-uitableviewcell

Comment: The reason I disagree is that I've read a number of other tutorials which specified the two lines I noted above in my comment, none stressed the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Then again, I can't get this to work so who knows what's right?

Comment: "The method allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row." – from the docs on `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You should give it a shot. I've done exactly the same things by doing what I recommended. Set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. This causes the UILabel to expand its height. Now in `heightforRowAtIndexPath`, compute the height and return it. Look at the example I linked to above.

Comment: Right - that is exactly what you need. Some rows may have 1 line, others may have 5 lines., The height for the cell is obviously different. Therefore, for each cell, you need to respond with the height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70599/discussion-between-zack-shapiro-and-tng).

Answer (score 0):

PLease implement it as well

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```